# What is isDev in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I've been watching about Javascript Build Automation with Gulp JS by John Papa and I saw that he uses **isDev** in a couple of parameters/arguments. I'm not sure what it actually does and I tried looking it up online and I couldn't find anything about it.

What does isDev actually do?

Comment: In JS, we name variable/function like that when it stores or returns Boolean value. Just a semantic convention.. Like JS also has methods `isArray()`, `isNaN()`

Comment: Since you mention Gulp.js i'd reckon it's to determine wether to build a development version or a production (prob. minified) version of the project. E.g. `npm run dev` vs `npm run build` or something like that.

Comment: [On this page](https://github.com/johnpapa/generator-hottowel/issues/25) I found possibly related sample code. Not in a comment by John himself, but perhaps he was the inspiration for it, or maybe John was inspired by it, or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I've suppose you are using Node.js or you are checking code which use Node.js.
So, isDev is a simple tool where you can check if you are in development enviroment.
You can learn more in its github repo: https://github.com/retrohacker/isDev

Comment: Yup, I'm using Node.js. This answer perfectly makes sense to me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a variable name with no special meaning in JavaScript. It's probably used for deciding whether to print debug statements, but I don't know.